# Facebook Account Management API 409 Conflict

Tags: facebook

I started to use the Facebook Account Management API to get, create and update users and it worked perfectly until I found this case for some specific email as username:

- I used the get user by username service, it returned 0 results

{
   "schemas": ["urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0"],
   "totalResults": 0,
   "itemsPerPage": 0,
   "startIndex": 1,
   "Resources": []
}

- then next step I called the create user but I got

{"Errors": [{
   "description": "User or Group Already Exists: The user or group you're trying to add already exists.",
   "code": 1789005
}]}

- Then I verified if there was a group permission, so it's set up to apply all groups.

I called the get all users and I checked all the user but I could not find it.

Somebody please can help me to know if there is another permission that I'm missing?

Thanks
Christopher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, there were some users created in another communities, so Workplace support removed these users.